# Confusing Laravel routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a list of users with a show method (with many to many roles) but I would like to have a different Profile page depending on the type of user (5 different types for the moment)

The method show of my UsersController shows the user well, but I still did an AdminController to create an administrators profile page.

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware('can:manage-admin')->group(function() {
Route::resource('formations', 'FormationsController');
Route::resource('utilisateurs', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
Route::resource('disciplines', 'DisciplinesController');
Route::resource('levels', 'LevelsController');

Route::get('/panel', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/profil', 'AdminController@profile')->name('admin.profile');
Route::post('/panel', 'AdminController@profileUpdate')->name('admin.profileUpdate');
```

});

However, when I try to display an administrator's profile from the Index page, I come across the Show method when I would like to display what the Profile method of my AdminController returns.

I know this is done with if, else in the Index blade page but I'm a little confused as to the exact route ...

Here's what I have in the index blade view :

```
<td width="10%">

                                <a href="{{ route('admin.utilisateurs.show', $user->id) }}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-1">
                                        <i class="fas fa-eye mr-1"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{{ route('admin.utilisateurs.edit', $user->id) }}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mr-1">
                                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt mr-1"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </a>

                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete-{{ $user->id }}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash mr-1"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand fully your troubles but depend of what I read is you're trying to redirect user to other page depending on Access Level the user has.

So this may help >>> https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

as I know you can't use **middleware** for working with blade
in answer of your question consider that column `user_type` id determine you user group
as an Simple method create blade for each of your group and return it in controller

```
function profile(){
     return view($user->user_type);
}
```